# Problem listing more than 1000 object keys - AWS-S3 - VB .net

Tags: vb.net, amazon-s3, digital, digital-ocean-spaces

For some reason, the code below does not list more than 1000 objects even after implementing the loop to continue listing using the continuation token assignment, which tells ListObjectsV2Request were to continue and stopping only when IsTruncated is true. My bucket has 33,000 objects and even if the prefix and key are empty strings the results always come back with 1000 objects. Can anybody help me understand why I always get 1000 objects?  Markers, are for the old version of the Amazon SDK.

```
''' <summary>
    ''' List objects in a AWS-S3 Bucket depending on the Prefix and Key passes to it.
    ''' See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html   
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="myBucketName">The name of the AWS-S3 bucket.</param>
    ''' <param name="FilePrefix">Act as a organizer. For example `TestFiles\` can be added in front of many files to group them</param>
    ''' <param name="Key_or_ActualFilename">The actual name of the file with extension. 
    ''' 'For example `ListOfCustomer1.xls` in TestFiles\ListOfCustomer1.xls
    ''' </param>
    ''' <remarks> 
    ''' Notes from Amazon documentation: 
    ''' Iterating through multi-page results:
    ''' As buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the complete results of a list query can be extremely large.
    ''' To manage large result sets, the Amazon S3 API supports pagination to split them into multiple responses. 
    ''' Each list keys response returns a page of up to 1,000 keys with an indicator indicating if the response is truncated.
    ''' You send a series of list keys requests until you have received all the keys. AWS SDK wrapper libraries provide the same pagination.
    ''' Function returns List(Of S3Object). Last modified by FGV on 03/20/2022 09:15PM
    ''' </remarks>
    Async Function ListAFileOrFilesInAWS_S3(myBucketName As String, FilePrefix As String, Key_or_ActualFilename As String) As Task(Of List(Of S3Object))
        Try
            Dim myClient As S3.IAmazonS3 = Get_AWS_S3_Client()
            '
            If myClient IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim SearchKey As String = ""
                If String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePrefix) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key_or_ActualFilename) Then
                    SearchKey = "" ' Search everywhere in the Bucket
                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePrefix) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key_or_ActualFilename) Then
                    SearchKey = FilePrefix ' Search for the file key only. more likely will return a file or two with the same unique filename or key part
                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePrefix) And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key_or_ActualFilename) = False Then
                    SearchKey = Key_or_ActualFilename ' Search for the prefix only , more likely will return multiple files with the same prefix
                ElseIf String.IsNullOrEmpty(FilePrefix) = False And String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key_or_ActualFilename) = False Then
                    SearchKey = FilePrefix & "\" & Key_or_ActualFilename
                End If
                '
                Dim mylistOfObjectsRequest As ListObjectsV2Request = New ListObjectsV2Request With {
                .BucketName = myBucketName,
                .Prefix = SearchKey
                }
                '
                ' for some reason it does not list more than 1000 objects,
                ' even after implementing the loop below and the continuation token assignment!
                Dim myListOfObjectsResponse As ListObjectsV2Response
                Do
                    myListOfObjectsResponse = Await myClient.ListObjectsV2Async(mylistOfObjectsRequest)
                    '
                    'For Each entry As S3Object In myListOfObjectsResponse.S3Objects

                    '    Console.WriteLine("key = {0} size = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Size)
                    'Next
                    'Console.WriteLine("Next Continuation Token: {0}", myListOfObjectsResponse.NextContinuationToken)
                    ''
                    mylistOfObjectsRequest.ContinuationToken = myListOfObjectsResponse.NextContinuationToken

                Loop While (myListOfObjectsResponse.IsTruncated)
                '
                ' code below for troubleshooting purpose only
                'For Each fileObject As S3Object In myListOfObjectsResponse.S3Objects
                '    If fileObject.Size > 0 Then ' if file size = 0 then is a folder must probably!
                '        MsgBox("Key Or File Full Path: " & fileObject.Key & "  - Size: " & fileObject.Size.ToString _
                '        & " Bytes  - Last Modified: " & fileObject.LastModified.ToString)
                '    End If
                'Next
                '
                ' using Linq to return the object everywhere in the bucket, but exclude the "folders" (object with size 0) themselves. 
                Return myListOfObjectsResponse.S3Objects.Where(Function(file) file.Size > 0).ToList()
                '
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            add_A_LogEntry(ErrorLogFilePath, "Unknown error listing files (object) via AWS-S3 client. Error: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
        Return Nothing
    End Function
```

Comment: @AndrewMorton What about it. It states what the code should do, and it is not doing it. That is the problem. Out of the tens of thousands of objects in the Bucket, I get two or three iterations of 1000 objects each and it then stops. Why? Why the IsTruncate is being set to true when clearly there is way more objects to list?

Comment: Have you checked the api documentation?  Are you sure you're not hitting some quota limit for AWS?

Comment: @Hursey, I have read as much as possible. There is no quota anywhere.